# Iterating over all files in OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT with Unicode

Tags: c, winapi, unicode

What is the recommended way of iterating over all files selected in an `OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT` open file dialog with Unicode enabled?

My first idea was something like this:

```
TCHAR *tmp = ofn.lpStrFile + ofn.nFileOffset;

while(*tmp) {
    wprintf("Got file: %s\n", tmp);
    tmp += wcslen(tmp) + 1;
}
```

But then it occurred to me that this won't work in case there are characters in the string buffer that can't be represented in 16 bits. So for a safe approach I'd first need to find out the byte length of the `tmp` `TCHAR` string, then cast the `TCHAR` pointer to `char` and add that byte length in each iteration. Something like this:

```
TCHAR *tmp = ofn.lpStrFile + ofn.nFileOffset;

while(*tmp) {
    wprintf("Got file: %s\n", tmp);
    tmp = (TCHAR *) (((char *) tmp)) + get_byte_len_of_tstr(tmp));
}
```

Note that `get_byte_len_of_tstr()` is just a placeholder for a function that would've to be written for this purpose. Since this approach looks somewhat clumsy, I'd first like to ask for some feedback whether this is really the way to go or whether I've missed or misunderstood something here...

Comment: You don't have a real problem, all characters can be represented with 16 bits.  Some just need two of them, that will not trip up your code.

Comment: But AFAIU wcslen() returns the count of characters in a TSTR, so if there is a character which needs 32 bit in the TSTR (i.e. two 16bit pairs), wcslen() will still only return 1 and this will mess up my pointer arithmetics in the code I posted above.

Comment: You *really* need to try this for yourself to see that this is not the case.  wcslen() counts wchar_t, not codepoints.  Turning wchar_t into a codepoint that represents a single glyph on the screen is the job of the text renderer.  It will quite often produce a single glyph from two wchar_t, even when they are not in the upper bit planes.  Happens for accented characters.

Comment: No, it won't. Like all string handling functions, `wcslen` returns numbers in multiples of code units. If a code point requires 2 code units to represent, `wcslen` will return 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example was on the right track, but has a couple of mistakes:

1. your variable should be declared `WCHAR*` instead of `TCHAR*`.
2. `wprintf()` does not accept a `char*` format string as input, it takes a `wchar_t*` instead.

```
WCHAR *tmp = ofn.lpStrFile + ofn.nFileOffset;
while (*tmp)
{
    wprintf(L"Got file: %s\n", tmp);
    tmp += (wcslen(tmp) + 1);
}
```

If you want to use `TCHAR` (and you really shouldn't, unless you need to support Win9x/ME), then it would look like this instead:

```
TCHAR *tmp = ofn.lpStrFile + ofn.nFileOffset;
while (*tmp)
{
    _tprintf(_T("Got file: %s\n"), tmp);
    tmp += (_tcslen(tmp) + 1);
}
```

That being said, your understanding of `wcslen()` is wrong (but your use of it is correct).  In Windows, a Unicode string is encoded in UTF-16, where each `WCHAR` element is a UTF-16 *codeunit*.  `wcslen()` counts the number of `WCHAR` elements in the string, not the number of Unicode *codepoints* that they represent, like you are thinking.  So, if a given *codepoint* requires a UTF-16 surrogate pair, it will use two `WCHAR` elements in the string, and `wcslen()` will count 2 for it.  Otherwise, it will use 1 `WCHAR` and `wcslen()` will count 1 for it.

The same is true for `strlen()` and MBCS strings, when a given Unicode codepoint is encoded using more than 1 codeunit (`char` element) in the string.

Comment: What is so bad about using `TCHAR`? Isn't it simply mapped to `WCHAR` if `UNICODE` is defined? (which is the case in my program)

Comment: That's correct. Using `TCHAR` and the other functions in `<tchar.h>` would be perfectly fine if you're building a Unicode application. What is *not* fine is casting it to `char`, @andreas.